# CarbonKit error on iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, autolayout

I have a small problem when use the library "https://github.com/ermalkaleci/CarbonKit" - CarbonKit. The library is excelent, but on iOS7 i have an error because a bug on iOS7 when use auto layout with tableview.

I had made a small sample project to show it:
https://github.com/prsolucoes/CarbonKitError

On project page you will see the error message and the line that generate the problem.

Can anyone help me with it please?

Comment: But surely this would be a question for Ermal Kaleci, would it not?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved and the solution is on repository.

We cannot use in iOS7 directly on TableView, we need recreate the UITableViewController using UIViewcontroller.

You can see the code on github repository.